# RDS Slow query log shows high number of rows than explain statement and I have no clue why?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have a procedure which runs through background script and shows up in AWS Top Sql but when I run explain manually on production server, it shows so less rows.

This is the procedure -

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procGetBookingForNoShowCharge;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procGetBookingForNoShowCharge()
BEGIN
    SELECT
        t11.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t0.CalendarEventBookingId,
            t0.CalendarEventId,
            t0.BookedFor,
            t0.UserId,
            t0.IsGuest,
            t0.GuestOf,
            t0.Status,
            t0.FitnessCenterId,
            t0.Department,
            t1.BookingType,
            t1.BookingTypeId,
            t1.EventName,
            t1.StartDateTime,
            t1.EndDateTime,
            t1.StartDateTimeInUtc,
            t1.Duration,
            t1.Source,
            t1.SourceId,
            t2.Status AS AttendanceStatus,
            t2.AttendanceTime,
            t3.SendMessageToNoShowMember,
            t4.FitnessCompanyId,
            t4.FitnessCompanyName,
            t4.BackendSoftware,
            t4.BackendSoftwareUrl,
            t4.BackendSoftwareId,
            t6.AbcFinancialClubNumber,
            t4.ActiveMemberStatus,
            t4.StripeConnectAccountType,
            t4.StripeConnectAccountId,
            t4.StripeShcConvenienceFee,
            t6.FitnessCenterName,
            t6.TimeZone,
            IFNULL(t7.ResourceName, t1.LocationName) AS Location,
            t8.Email,
            t8.StripeDefaultCardId,
            t8.StripeCustomerId,
            t8.StripeStandardDefaultCardId,
            t8.StripeStandardCustomerId,
            t8.TimeFirstLogin,
            t8.ContactStatus,
            t8.IsAuthenticated,
            t8.BounceType,
            t9.FullName
        FROM
            CalendarEventBooking t0
            INNER JOIN CalendarEvent t1 ON t1.CalendarEventId = t0.CalendarEventId
            LEFT JOIN CalendarEventAttendance t2 ON t2.CalendarEventId = t0.CalendarEventId AND t2.AttendedFor = t0.BookedFor AND t2.UserId = t0.UserId AND t2.MemberId = t0.MemberId AND t2.UserName = t0.UserName AND t2.IsGuest = t0.IsGuest
            INNER JOIN BookingSetting t3 ON t3.BookingType = t1.BookingType AND t3.BookingSubType = t0.BookedFor AND t3.BookingTypeId = t1.BookingTypeId AND t3.FitnessCompanyId = t1.FitnessCompanyId
            INNER JOIN FitnessCompany t4 ON t4.FitnessCompanyId = t1.FitnessCompanyId
            LEFT JOIN BookingAndAttendancePolicy t5 ON t5.FitnessCompanyId = t4.FitnessCompanyId AND FIND_IN_SET(t0.Department, t5.Department) AND t5.Type = 'classes'
            INNER JOIN FitnessCenter t6 ON t6.FitnessCenterId = t0.FitnessCenterId
            LEFT JOIN FitnessCenterResource t7 ON t7.FitnessCenterId = t6.FitnessCenterId AND t7.ResourceId = t1.ResourceId
            INNER JOIN Users t8 ON t8.UserId = IF(t0.IsGuest, t0.GuestOf, t0.UserId)
            INNER JOIN Profile t9 ON t9.UserId = t8.UserId AND t9.FitnessCompanyId = t8.FitnessCompanyId
            INNER JOIN BookingSetting t10 ON t10.BookingType = t1.BookingType AND t10.BookingSubType = t0.BookedFor AND t10.BookingTypeId = t1.BookingTypeId AND t10.FitnessCompanyId = t4.FitnessCompanyId
        WHERE
            t0.Status = 'confirmed'
            AND
            (
                t0.NoShowChargeStatus IS NULL
                OR t0.NoShowChargeStatus = 'pending'
            )
            AND t1.Source IN ('Google', 'AbcFinancial')
            AND t1.BookingType = 'classes'
            AND t1.EventStatus IN ('open', 'completed')
            AND t3.SendMessageToNoShowMember IS NOT NULL
            AND t1.StartDateTimeInUtc <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL t3.SendMessageToNoShowMember HOUR)
            AND t1.StartDateTimeInUtc >= t3.NoShowMemberStartDateTime
            AND t10.BookingType = 'classes'
            AND t10.SendMessageToNoShowMember IS NOT NULL
        UNION
        SELECT
            t0.CalendarEventBookingId,
            t0.CalendarEventId,
            t0.BookedFor,
            t0.UserId,
            t0.IsGuest,
            t0.GuestOf,
            t0.Status,
            t0.FitnessCenterId,
            t0.Department,
            t1.BookingType,
            t1.BookingTypeId,
            t1.EventName,
            t1.StartDateTime,
            t1.EndDateTime,
            t1.StartDateTimeInUtc,
            t1.Duration,
            t1.Source,
            t1.SourceId,
            t2.Status AS AttendanceStatus,
            t2.AttendanceTime,
            t3.SendMessageToNoShowMember,
            t4.FitnessCompanyId,
            t4.FitnessCompanyName,
            t4.BackendSoftware,
            t4.BackendSoftwareUrl,
            t4.BackendSoftwareId,
            t6.AbcFinancialClubNumber,
            t4.ActiveMemberStatus,
            t4.StripeConnectAccountType,
            t4.StripeConnectAccountId,
            t4.StripeShcConvenienceFee,
            t6.FitnessCenterName,
            t6.TimeZone,
            IFNULL(t7.ResourceName, t1.LocationName) AS Location,
            t8.Email,
            t8.StripeDefaultCardId,
            t8.StripeCustomerId,
            t8.StripeStandardDefaultCardId,
            t8.StripeStandardCustomerId,
            t8.TimeFirstLogin,
            t8.ContactStatus,
            t8.IsAuthenticated,
            t8.BounceType,
            t9.FullName
        FROM
            CalendarEventBooking t0
            INNER JOIN CalendarEvent t1 ON t1.CalendarEventId = t0.CalendarEventId
            LEFT JOIN CalendarEventAttendance t2 ON t2.CalendarEventId = t0.CalendarEventId AND t2.AttendedFor = t0.BookedFor AND t2.UserId = t0.UserId AND t2.MemberId = t0.MemberId AND t2.UserName = t0.UserName AND t2.IsGuest = t0.IsGuest
            INNER JOIN BookingSetting t3 ON t3.BookingType = t1.BookingType AND t3.BookingSubType = t0.BookedFor AND t3.BookingTypeId = t1.BookingTypeId AND t3.FitnessCompanyId = t1.FitnessCompanyId
            INNER JOIN FitnessCompany t4 ON t4.FitnessCompanyId = t1.FitnessCompanyId
            LEFT JOIN BookingAndAttendancePolicy t5 ON t5.FitnessCompanyId = t4.FitnessCompanyId AND FIND_IN_SET(t0.Department, t5.Department) AND t5.Type = 'classes'
            INNER JOIN FitnessCenter t6 ON t6.FitnessCenterId = t0.FitnessCenterId
            LEFT JOIN FitnessCenterResource t7 ON t7.FitnessCenterId = t6.FitnessCenterId AND t7.ResourceId = t1.ResourceId
            INNER JOIN Users t8 ON t8.UserId = IF(t0.IsGuest, t0.GuestOf, t0.UserId)
            INNER JOIN Profile t9 ON t9.UserId = t8.UserId AND t9.FitnessCompanyId = t8.FitnessCompanyId
            INNER JOIN BookingSetting t10 ON t10.BookingType = t1.BookingType AND t10.BookingSubType = t0.BookedFor AND t10.BookingTypeId = t1.BookingTypeId AND t10.FitnessCompanyId = t4.FitnessCompanyId
        WHERE
            t0.Status IN ('cancelled', 'transferred')
            AND t0.IsLateCancelled IS TRUE
            AND
            (
                (
                    t5.Id IS NOT NULL
                    AND t5.IsNoShowChargeForLateCancellation IS TRUE
                )
                OR
                (
                    t5.Id IS NULL
                    AND t4.IsNoShowChargeForLateCancellation IS TRUE
                )
            )
            AND
            (
                t0.NoShowChargeStatus IS NULL
                OR t0.NoShowChargeStatus = 'pending'
            )
            AND t1.Source IN ('Google', 'AbcFinancial')
            AND t1.BookingType = 'classes'
            AND t1.EventStatus IN ('open', 'completed')
            AND t3.SendMessageToNoShowMember IS NOT NULL
            AND t1.StartDateTimeInUtc <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL t3.SendMessageToNoShowMember HOUR)
            AND t1.StartDateTimeInUtc >= t3.NoShowMemberStartDateTime
            AND t10.BookingType = 'classes'
            AND t10.SendMessageToNoShowMember IS NOT NULL
    ) t11
    ORDER BY
        t11.StartDateTimeInUtc ASC
    LIMIT
        10
    ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

From Slow log query -

## Query_time: 15.602992  Lock_time: 0.625710 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 231570

SET timestamp=1693998962;

```
CALL procGetBookingForNoShowCharge();
```

Attaching screenshot of explain statement which I have run on production server.
[screenshot of explain statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA6Fy.png)
I need to find a proper solution as this issue keeps coming on my server again and again